# How to setup sshuttle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, ssh, parrot-os

I'm using ParrotOS and currently doing prolabs Dante on HTB but I'm having trouble pivoting.

I've installed sshuttle with `sudo apt-get install sshuttle`, however, when I simply try and run "sshuttle" it comes back with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sshuttle", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sshuttle==1.0.5.dev17+g299854d', 'console_scripts', 'sshuttle')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sshuttle-1.0.5.dev17+g299854d-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/cmdline.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sshuttle.client as client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sshuttle-1.0.5.dev17+g299854d-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/client.py", line 13, in <module>
    import sshuttle.ssh as ssh
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sshuttle-1.0.5.dev17+g299854d-py2.7.egg/sshuttle/ssh.py", line 7, in <module>
    import importlib.util
ImportError: No module named util
```

However, when I try `pip install util` or `pip3 install util` it says it can't find any packages called util.

How can I fix this error to run sshuttle?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on raspberry pi. I installed sshuttle successfully with

`sudo pip3 install sshuttle`

Somehow sshuttle was using python 2.7 that cannot understand:
`import importlib.util`

Installing with pip3 forces the installed sshuttle to use python3